# zkoss Color Picker CE

Tags: zk

do Color Picker in zkoss framework is available for Community Version?

Comment: no (i check http://www.zkoss.org/product/edition.dsp)

Comment: is there is any way to use the color picker

Answer (score 1):

There's a third-party component on google code now.
http://code.google.com/p/zk-colorbox/

Answer (score 0):

you can integrate a [jQuery's plugin](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/) to work with ZK. Here is [the tutorial of jQuery4j](http://code.google.com/p/jquery4j/wiki/HowToWrap)